# Is it possible to draw text with shadows using the NSString UIKit additions?

Tags: ios, uikit

Is it possible to draw with simple text shadows when using the NSString UIKit additions? I mean without writing code to draw twice in two colors, as can be done with various UIKit classes such as UILabel and its `shadowColor` and `shadowOffset` properties, and also without doing actual blur shadows via `CGContextSetShadow` (which are bound to be much more expensive).

[Apple's doc for these extensions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) actually include constants (at the very bottom) including `UITextAttributeTextShadowColor` and `UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset` which implies that it is possible, but I don't see any possible usage of these in the actual methods.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. The `UITextAttributeTextShadow...` keys are intended for when using a text attribute dictionary with, for example, `UIAppearance` methods:

   ```
   NSDictionary *attributes = @{UITextAttributeTextShadowColor  : [UIColor blackColor],
                                UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset : [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(2.0, 0.0)],
                                UITextAttributeTextColor        : [UIColor yellowColor]};

   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes];
   ```

   The `UITextAttributeTextShadow...` keys are designed for use only in those methods that accept a text attributes dictionary.
2. The closest equivalent key when drawing text strings is the use of attributed strings with the `NSShadowAttributeName` key:

   ```
   - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
   {
       UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:50];

       NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
       shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
       shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 0.0;
       shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 2.0);

       NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSShadowAttributeName          : shadow,
                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor yellowColor],
                                    NSFontAttributeName            : font};

       NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"this has shadows" attributes:attributes];

       [attributedText drawInRect:rect];
   }
   ```

   If you're concerned about the performance hit of a shadow algorithm capable of doing a bezier curve shadow, though, `NSShadow` may suffer from that. But doing some benchmarks, changing the `shadowBlurRadius` dramatically affects performance. For example, animating the rotation of a complex multi-line text with a `shadowBlurRadius` of `10.0` on a slow iPhone 3GS achieved a frame rate of 31 fps, but changing `shadowBlurRadius` to `0.0` yielded a frame rate of 60 fps.

   Bottom line, using a shadow blur radius of `0.0` eliminates most (if not all) of the computational overhead of a bezier generated shadow.
3. FYI, I experience a similar performance improvement by setting the `blur` value to `0.0` for `CGContextSetShadow`, just like I experienced with the attributed text rendition above.

Bottom line, I don't think you should fear the computational overhead of bezier-based shadows as long as you use a blur radius of `0.0`. I wouldn't be surprised if writing the text twice yourself, once for the shadow and again for the foreground color, might even be a bit more efficient, but I'm not sure if the difference will be observable. But I don't know of any API call that will do that for you (other than `CGContextSetShadow` with `blur` of `0.0`).

Comment: Thanks! I'm still mystified by the presence of those shadow constants at the bottom of the [Apple doc for NSString UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) but that must be a mistake on their part. Great to know that 0 blur shadows aren't inefficient as per your experience!

Comment: @Clafou Perhaps I'm not following your question, but those shadow constants are used for methods that take a "text attribute dictionary", such as the `UIAppearance` methods, as I illustrated in my first point. I guess it doesn't matter, since I don't think they're of no use for your current challenge, but if you ever get into `UIAppearance`, you'll use those constants.

Comment: What I mean is, why does Apple document those text attribute constants in the [NSString drawing methods page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) (which don't use these attributes) instead of in the [NSAttributedString page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) (which do use them as per your example code)?

Comment: Or to be exact maybe they should be somewhere related to UIAppearance. But their choosing to document them on a seemingly unrelated page is confusing. Unless I am still missing something...

Comment: @Clafou Yeah, I agree, it's a curious place to put it. Looks like they just threw a bunch of `NSString` addition stuff together in one doc.

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet uses CALayer to add shadow around the edges of the characters in a UILabel:

```
 _helloLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
[_helloLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[_helloLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[_helloLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[_helloLabel setFont:[UIFont lightApplicationFontOfSize:30]];

_helloLabel.layer.shadowColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xd04942).CGColor;
_helloLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
_helloLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0;
_helloLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;

[self addSubview:_helloLabel];
```

. . normally this would add a shadow around the border, but UILabel seems to treat these properties as a special case.

Comment: Thanks Jasper! I am drawing directly into the graphics context using Core Graphics, and using the NSString UIKit additions is pretty handy. I am achieving something similar to your answer by adding `CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(1.0f, -1.0f), 0.0f, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);` before my drawing but I think this is less efficient than the shadowColor/shadowOffset thing that is implied by the constants in the doc.

Comment: Oh cool - I didn't realize you were at the drawing level . . . nice work!