# Programmatically add a drop shadow to text in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I define a title object with attributes for how the text will appear. Is there a way to also add a drop shadow?

Obj-C

```
_titleAttributes =  @{
                         NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor],
                         NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Harabara" size:25.0f]
                         };
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129108/is-it-possible-to-draw-text-with-shadows-using-the-nsstring-uikit-additions

Comment: Actually, I just saw in the docs that the shadow attributes are deprecated in iOS 7.0, so it may not be of much help.

Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Keys_for_Text_Attributes_Dictionaries